# confusion regarding elasticity of a demand curve

Tags: elasticity, demand

The following question is on a quiz at Marginal Revolution University:
https://mru.org/practice-questions/calculating-elasticity-demand-practice-questions

> The elasticity of demand is 2.0. Is the demand curve relatively steep
> or flat? Will a fall in price raise total revenue or lower it? Note:
> we present the elasticity in terms of its absolute value.

The official answer is "relatively flat; raise total revenue".

I can't understand this; isn't it true that elasticity > 1 means higher responsiveness of demand to changes in price?  And isn't 1.0 defined as neither steep nor flat, and anything above 1.0 being steeper?

I can understand that a fall in price will lead to a huge surge in demand, because of the high elasticity, and therefore more profits.

I missed another question on the quiz that, for me, should be explicable in terms of the same reasoning as above.

> The elasticity of demand is 1.1. Is the demand curve relatively steep
> or flat? Will a fall in price raise total revenue or lower it? Note:
> we present the elasticity in terms of its absolute value.

Again, the official answer is "relatively flat; raise total revenue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that the higher the elasticity is the more flat the demand curve will be. A higher elasticity means that demand responds disproportionately more to change in prices. In fact an example of demand curve where elasticity $ | \epsilon|  = \infty$ would be a flat horizontal demand curve.

The reason for this is that elasticity of demand tells you how much quantity demanded (plotted by convention on x-axis) changes in response to change in price (by convention plotted on y-axis). In order for a small price change (small distance 'traveled' across y-axis) to have large impact on quantity (distance 'traveled' across x-axis) the curve has to be relatively 'flat' since the slope which will be the rise/run of tangent line at a given point must be relatively small.

For example if elasticity $| \epsilon | = 2$ that means that $1\%$ decrease in price increases quantity demanded by $2\%$. Since total revenue is defined as price times quantity $P*Q$ if $P$ decreases only by $1\%$ but $Q$ increases by $2\%$ the total revenue has to increase.  So the answer provided is correct.

To actually showcase how the demand becomes more 'flat' I generated 3 constant elasticity of demand functions ($P=Q^{1/\epsilon}$) using R for natural numbers $Q = 1, ..., 10$. The blue demand curve has constant elasticity of $0.5$, the orange one $2$ and the red one has constant elasticity of $5$ (all expressed in absolute value). You see as the elasticity increases the demand graph becomes more 'flat'.

[image]